# CMake "TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES cannot find -lfoo" but it is in the same directory as another library

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, clion

As mentioned above i have problems with compiling my c++ project (using CMake) which uses some dynamic libraries (.so).
There are 3 libs in my directory (i.e. `home/sources/lib/`). When i only tell the compiler (in the CMake file) to use the first lib (`foo1.so`) it works (only this file, the order does not matter). But it does not work with any of the other libs (`foo2.so` and `foo2.so`). All 3 files have the .so extension.

**Note:** The directory and file names were changed but the structure is the same.
The libraries i am using were not compiled / created by me and are from a 3rd party. (it would not matter when they were broken, would it?)

---

And this is how my CMake file looks like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(MyProj)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -pthread -m64")
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("/home/sources/include")
LINK_DIRECTORIES("/home/sources/lib")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(MyProj ${SOURCE_FILES})

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(MyProj foo1.so)
```

Changing the above line to this does not work anymore:

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(MyProj foo1.so foo2.so foo3.so)
```

Just another way to write it (does not help)

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(MyProj foo1.so)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(MyProj foo2.so)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(MyProj foo3.so)
```

And as mentioned above: ALL 3 libraries are in the SAME directory (which i refer to with `LINK_DIRECTORIES`)

And this is the error i get when trying to compile with the other libs (as said only `foo1.so` works):

```
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable MyProj
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfoo2
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfoo3
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [MyProj] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/MyProj.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/MyProj.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [MyProj] Error 2
```

P.S.: I did some research before posting here but did not find any otherone with this "strange" problem. And for sure i wouldn't have come so far with my CMake file without some googling skills ^^

Comment: Probably, `foo2.so` and `foo3.so` have incorrect format for given platform, while `foo1.so` is good. You may use `file` command for each of them and compare output.

Comment: Thanks for this advice (did not think about the `file` command...). But they _are_ the same:


`foo3.so: ELF 64-bit LSB  shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=..., stripped`

`foo2.so: ELF 64-bit LSB  shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=..., stripped`

`foo1.so: ELF 64-bit LSB  shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=..., stripped`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure, but it seems to me that CMake is looking for `libfoo1.so` whereas the file is actually `foo1.so` (the same applies for `foo2` and `foo3`)

Try ["importing"](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#imported-targets) the libs:

```
add_library(foo1 SHARED IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET foo1 PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION "/home/sources/lib/libfoo1.so")
# same thing for foo2 and foo3 ...

target_link_libraries(MyProj foo1 foo2 foo3)
```

**EDIT**

There's also the possibility to provide the full path to the library:

```
target_link_libraries(MyProj "/home/sources/lib/libfoo1.so"
                             "/home/sources/lib/libfoo2.so"
                             "/home/sources/lib/libfoo3.so")
```

Comment: Check out the edit ;) Apart from using `fooX` to refer to `libfooX.so` or `libfooX.a`, these are (AFAIK) the 2 methods for linking external libs in CMake. I personally prefer the "imported target" approach because it more flexible (e.g. you can set the `IMPORTED_LOCATION` property for each platform without changing the `target_link_libraries()` call). It also requires less typing if you have multiple targets using the same external lib.

Comment: i tried the **EDIT** method before writing here and this one worked neither. Only the `IMPORTED` way helped here - i can not understand why...